# Why is 'true instanceof Boolean' equal to false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following indicates the expression "true instanceof Boolean" evaluates to false. Why would this expression evaluate to false?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $result = $('#result');
  
  if(true instanceof Boolean) {
    $result.append('I\'m a Boolean!');
  } else {
    $result.append('I\'m something other than a Boolean!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What you probably want for your expression is `typeof true == 'boolean'`

Answer (score 20):

The value `true` is a boolean primitive — that's "boolean" with a lower-case "b". It is not an object.

Similarly, `"hello"` is not an instance of String, because a string primitive is not an object either.

You can test for primitive types with the `typeof` operator.

The distinction between primitive values and object values can be a little confusing in JavaScript because the language implicitly wraps primitives in appropriate object wrappers when primitives are used like object references. That's why you can write

```
var length = "hello world".length;
```

The string is implicitly converted to a String instance for that `.` operation to work. You can even do that with a boolean:

```
var trueString = true.toString();
```

It happens with numbers too, though the syntax gets in the way sometimes:

```
var failure = 2.toString(); // an error
var success = (2).toString(); // works
```

Comment: Thanks Pointy, seems instanceOf only works with objects and not primitive types! Good answer.

Comment: Good answer!  But a little confusing, maybe tag on a code example to the end for those less familiar:  if (typeof true === "boolean") ....

Answer (score -2):

[The Boolean object is an object wrapper for a boolean value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

So the boolean value and the wrapper object are not the same thing.

Also, [boolean objects are verboten](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style). In other words it isn't good style to ever use a Boolean object.

Comment: @Shashank yes there are: try `true.toString()`

Comment: You are missing new. Try `new Boolean(true) instanceof Boolean` and you will get true.

Comment: @Pointy That's not really an object wrapper. It's just a change to another primitive type, an object wrapper would be like Object(true).

Comment: @DavidMichaelCabinessJr. Ah, I was wrong, comment removed.

Comment: @Pointy Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that's because JS implicitly converts the primitive types to their object forms when you use the dot operator.

Comment: @Shashank yes exactly - the '.' operator forces that implicit conversion.  (Whether a particular implementation *really* builds a new object or not, I'm not sure; it'd be kind-of hard to tell I guess.)